# Querying geodesics (shortest paths) using sDNA

Tags: sdna

I am querying geodesics with sDNA 4.0.2.

Is there a way to output a set of geodesics based on specified origin-destination pairs (specified with polyline/link IDs)?

Right now when I use the "Geodesics" tool and enter the Origin IDs and Destination IDs, it will output geodesics of all possible combinations of the input origins and destinations. This is not very efficient computation- and storage-wise, because I only need to know a subset of those geodesics.

For each geodesic, I would like to get its length and the IDs of the polylines/links that comprise the geodesic. I think the program has already computed all the shortest path between all possible origins and destinations, but I am not sure if that information is available for the end users to play with in the ArcGIS tool interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible using a matrix for OD (origin-destination) weighting.

1. Define a zone field on your network - either string or numeric - so long as you give a different value to every link you want to use as origin or destination. (Actually the best idea is probably to copy the object ID field, that would work - in other words defining a zoning system where there is a 1-1 correspondence between links and zones. If you have millions of links, sDNA will run faster if you define a single zone value for all the links you're not interested in, thus reducing the zone count substantially. But I'm not sure how much faster and whether it will make a huge difference).
2. Make a [2d table in list format](https://sdna-open.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide_to_individual_tools.html#id7) in which you can list every origin-destination pair you want a geodesic for, and give it a nonzero weight (e.g. 1). For example, for geodesics from link 45-63 and 46-62 you could write in a CSV file:

> list, 2
>   zone, zone, weight
>   45,63,1
>   46,62,1

3. Run sDNA geodesics tool; specify `skipzeroweightorigins` in advanced config (to avoid calculating geodesics from origins you are not going to output) and possibly `skipzeroweightdestinations`. Remember to pass your CSV file as an OD matrix, and you can leave the `origins` and `destinations` fields blank as the matrix will do the relevant filtering for you.